# Solutions to the Following PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was wondering if there is any solutions for the following PDE:
$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}$$
here $\alpha=\alpha (x,y),\beta=\beta (x,y)$.
 Clearly the map $\mu: \Bbb{R^2} \to \Bbb{R^2}$ with components $(\alpha, \beta)$ is not invertible anywhere in $\Bbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Please note that you've given us one equation and two unknown functions so there will be a family of $\beta$'s that works for virtually any choice of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}$$
In fact this equation creates a relationship between two functions $\alpha(x,y)$ and $\beta(x,y)$. Thus the question of solving it for $\alpha$ AND $\beta$ is a non-sens.

The question is to solve the PDE for one function, given the other.

For example, let $\alpha(x,y)$ be a given function. Then, the question is to solve the PDE for $\beta$

Let $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}=f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}=g(x,y)$, both given functions since $\alpha(x,y)$ is given.

$$f(x,y) \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y}-g(x,y)\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}=0$$